# Trying to access another class that is outside my Unity script but casting is failing

Tags: unity, unityscript

I am trying to reference a class that is outside my unity script using GetComponent.

```
private FlyThroughCamera camera;

void Start () 
{
    camera = GetComponent(typeof(FlyThroughCamera)) as FlyThroughCamera;
    camera.DoSomething();
}
```

Although the class exists the cast is failing and returning null.

The other class is defined as:

```
public class FlyThroughCamera : MonoBehaviour
```

Where have I gone wrong?

EDIT:

[image: Linked FlyThroughCamera]

Comment: Are you sure you have added the FlyThroughCamera component to your gameobject?

Comment: Also no need to tag this with unityscript since it seems you are using C# : )

Comment: I have added the FlyThroughCamera on my GameObject in the inspector but the cast will revert it to null.  If I delete the cast code then I will get a warning about hiding inherited members because it is not instantiated in any way.

Comment: If you just log the return of your GetComponent call without the cast, what does it print?

Comment: Debug.Log(GetComponent(typeof(FlyThroughCamera))) returns null

Comment: You do not have any FlyThroughCamera component. I think you are misunderstanding the basics of Unity3D.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would caution against shadowing the `MonoBehaviour.camera` field.

I recommend the generic form of `GetComponent()`.

```
private FlyThroughCamera flyCamera;

void Start () 
{
     flyCamera = GetComponent<FlyThroughCamera>();
     flyCamera .DoSomething();
}
```

Comment: GetComponent still returns null, even though the class exists and is linked via the Inspector window.

Comment: That's strange?... It might help if you add a screenshot of the inspector to your question.

Comment: I have added a screenshot as requested.

Comment: There is no `FlyThroughCamera` component on that game object! `getComponent()` will return `null` if unable to find a component of the specified type.

Comment: You have however already defined a value for your camera variable, so just remove the `GetComponent()` line and it should work.

Comment: Ah, I see.  That's what has been confusing me.  Thank you.

Comment: I'm still getting a warning that I am hiding an inherited member 'UnityEngine.Component.camera' if I go with this approach though.

Comment: Please see the first line of my answer, and note that I used a different variable name in my code.

Comment: So 'camera' is a protected name.